# Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen and preferences button

Tags: android, fullscreen, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, preferences

I am working on an app for tablet that uses the `Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen`: my tablet is under android 4.1.1 and the settings button should be on the top right corner of the app, but with such a style, the button (three little squares aligned vertically) is not visible... how can I fix that?

Answer (score 0):

The button you are talking about is part of the title bar. So if you request to hide that one, your button is of course not accessible anymore.

You have to provide a button in your layout to access your settings screen. Or show the title bar.

Comment: it's a bit annoying as on my SGS2 this button is on the phone... :( and I don't want to loose the space of all the title bar...

Comment: You can provide different layouts for tablets and phones. I don't see any other alternative.

Answer (score 0):

You can use context menus for resolving this thing ... i was having the same problem... and if you want to use legacy overflow button (the three dots) please refer to this link http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2012/01/say-goodbye-to-menu-button.html